# Ubuntu installed on USB doesn't boot propely on other computers

Tags: boot, 16.04, usb

I've installed Ubuntu on a USB drive to install programs on it and then use the drive to boot Ubuntu and use the programs in places I don't have the adminstrative rights to the Windows system (school mainly).

The drive and the system work perfectly fine on my main PC and I've been able to install my programs but I can't boot into Ubuntu on any other computer using the drive (I've tried it on my main PC (works) + three other PCs (don't work).

The problem shouldn't be with the graphics driver at least, that was the only problem I found online people having and did all the fixes (so I don't use any proprietary drivers).

When trying to boot into Ubuntu on my laptop it gives me error something like "failure reading sector *somethingsomething* a few times and the in throws me into this grub environment I have no idea about.

Any help appreciated, faster better

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple suggestions:
1. Check the bios settings on other computers and check if the boot mode for the usb is set to 'Windows UEFI.' If it is, try to change it to an option labelled 'other OS' or something along those lines
2. from grub, navigate to 'extra options for ubuntu' or something similar (I forget the exact text), navigate to recovery mode and boot normally from there.

I hope I was able to help, or at least put you on the right track